# Amazon SES persistent audit log

Tags: amazon-ses

I am using Amazon SES to send transactional application emails. I want an audit log of every email sent by the system.

As an example, I might want to see a log of every email we sent to john.smith@example.com.

I followed the instructions for using [Cloudwatch to log SES events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-retrieving-cloudwatch.html). However, this only actually logs metrics, not data logs. So all I see in Cloudwatch is a graph of how many emails were sent at different times under the metrics tab. I can't search a log anywhere to find individual SES events.

I also looked into using [Cloudtrail to log SES events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html), but Cloudtrail only logs management events. It does not log data events like emails being sent.

I have setup SNS notifications on all SES events (such as send or bounce). This is really useful, but does not achieve my aim of having a long term audit log.

As far as I can tell Amazon do not support the kind of logging I want to record. Maybe I could write events to our application database as we produce them, but it seems a shame to have to introduce my own custom logging system.

Does anyone know a way to have AWS store my SES data events?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Amazon doesn't have any easy to monitor you ask, an easier solution would be to add a Configuration set header and a unique message tag whenever any email is being sent to  john.smith@example.com, In configuration set, you can enable Cloudwatch or preferred SNS Destination and create delivery dashboard using link below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/bouncecomplaintdashboard.html

This isn't the logs but It creates a nice excel file of email details which can be used for Audit purpose.

Comment: Useful link, thanks. It could easily be adapted for storing all email events, not just bounces. As you say, not quite what I want, but a useful tutorial none the less.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket with AWS about this, here is their response.

---

I understand that you wanted to know whether SES provides logs about events of an email that was accepted by SES for delivery in a searchable format. Please correct me if I’m wrong.

SES provides logs as notification[1] for each event(Delivery, Bounce, Complaint) to SNS and it doesn’t provide event logs in a consolidated manner which would be helpful for indexing according to email addresses and searching purpose. However, in SNS you can configure a variety of subscriber like(Email, SQS, Lambda, HTTP endpoint) where the logs in JSON format would be delivered. In the destination of SNS like Lambda and HTTP Endpoint or email, you can parse the JSON file and store in a suitable format which would be helpful for indexing and searching purpose.

If SQS is being used, each JSON log will be stored individually in the SQS queue for some time. You can periodically query the SQS endpoint and retrieve the logs and consolidate it to a single file and use it for analysis.

Apart from that, unfortunately SES doesn’t provide any other format of logs for an email it accepted for delivery.

Do let me know if you require any further assistance, I’ll be happy to help.

References:

[1]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-using-notifications.html

Comment: yes, that will cost you a lot to parse all emails and look for one recipient , its better to have a rule to add the configuration-set for particular recipient before sending it to ses and then trigger SNS only for that and store the json somewhere.